# Operation returned an invalid status 'Unauthorized' while creating azure static web app

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm following the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/introduction-to-azure-app-service/7-create-html-web-app) to create an azure static web app from the cloud shell, using the command:

`az webapp up --location westindia --name static-webapp-test --html`

Getting the following `Unauthorized` error :

`The webapp 'static-webapp-test' doesn't exist Creating Resource group 'anubhav.das_rg_8008' ... Resource group creation complete Creating AppServicePlan 'anubhav.das_asp_4721' ... Operation returned an invalid status 'Unauthorized'`

Answer (score 0):

- I have seen these type of errors like preventing the user from creation of resources due to role restrictions or access level restrictions in the subscription.
- Please check your role (should be owner or contributor or user access administrator) and filters added in the Azure Active Directory.
- It is recommended to use the latest version of CLI.
- If you are using the older version run the below cmdlet to upgrade the CLI to latest version :

```
az upgrade --yes
```

I have followed the steps provided in the given [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/introduction-to-azure-app-service/7-create-html-web-app), we are able to create the static web app successfully :

1. Selected Azure Cloud Shell and given the following settings like my subscription, location, resource group name, storage account name, file share name for working on the cloud shell.
   [image]
2. Cloned the git hub project to my azure account as you can see in below screenshot:

[image]

Also created another same type of application with the name you have given:
[image]

- As I can see there is no issue in creation of static html web app though I have existing resource group using for working with cloud shell, it is creating new resource group for the web app purpose by  using the given commands in the documentation and working good without any access restriction like authorization as my role belongs to Contributor.